# Is it possible to update app in Samsung Galaxy App Store to consolidate multiple build flavors?

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, package-name

I currently build two flavors of my app:

- AppAndroid.apk --> Available on Google Play store
- AppSamsung.apk --> Available on the Samsung Galaxy store

I am looking to consolidate the two apks into just one and have a few questions:

1. What happens if I upload AppAndroid to the Samsung Galaxy store to my current AppSamsung listing? Will it fail because it has a different package name? Would I have to create a new listing?
2. If it does upload successfully, what would the user experience be? If they already had AppSamsung on their device, and then AppAndroid became available to download on the galaxy store, would AppAndroid be installed alongside AppSamsung?
3. What would happen if the user already had AppAndroid installed from the play store and then they navigate to the Galaxy store? Would they get prompted to open the app?
4. If AppAndroid is available on the Galaxy Store (v1.0), and then I add a new version (v2.0) to the Play Store, will that cause issues? The submission process for Samsung takes longer than the play store, so it is likely that at times the Play store version will be newer than what is in the galaxy store.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the Samsung store, so I can't comment on that. But facts that might be useful:

- on Android you can't "update" from one package name (application id) to another. They are considered two separate applications, and so I suspect you will need a separate listing
- on Android you can't have two copies of the same app with the same package name. So if you change to the same package name, it won't install from both stores.
- Google Play respects the App store that installed your app, so won't update it unless it came from Google Play. However, this also means having the same app in different App stores doesn't cause any issues from Google Play.